# iOS - how do I only update my UIImage on the UIView

Tags: ios, uiview, uiimage

I've got an UIImage on a UIView. Instead of redrawing the entire UIView, I just want to redraw that specific UIImage. How do I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UIImage on a UIView is not possible. I Think you mean a UIImageView on a UIView.

You can send to the UIImageView...

```
[yourImageView setNeedsDisplay];
```